# How to vertically align glyph?

Tags: html, css, alignment, glyph

I need the glyph to be vertically aligned to the text. Now it looks more like it's attached to the bottom.

Here as an example

```
<a href="#">Zoom</a>

a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:before { content:"\2039"; }
```

and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gq1xbn1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest to do just with vertical-align and a fixed offset. For example

```
a:before { content:"\2039"; vertical-align:0.1em; }
```

```css
a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:before { content:"\2039"; vertical-align:0.1em; }
```

```html
<a href="#">Zoom</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/csh0da6o/3/

Comment: The offset needs to depend on the characters involved and on the font used, since this is really about aligning *glyphs*, and you cannot refer to glyph metrics in CSS. However, the use of the `em` unit avoids an addition dependency, dependency on font size. Here `0.1em` is indeed a suitable value for the specific context.

Comment: Great, thats a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can apply `vertical-align: top` to the text with `vertical align: middle` on the glyph to achieve this behaviour. By adjusting the `line-height` of the glyph you can change its offset.

Here's a JsFiddle with the glyph aligned to the middle: http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/csh0da6o/2/

Comment: Not working :( the glyph stays at the bottom. It should be vertically centered to the text.